# Get maximum closest number from int list

Tags: c#, linq

I have number list like below and I should check a condition to get most suitable match.

```
List<int> numbers= new List<int>();
numbers.Add(1000);
numbers.Add(3000);
numbers.Add(5500);
numbers.Add(7000);
```

If I send a value to check it should check like below examples

Scenario 1:
If I send a value less than or equal 1000 to check, it should return 1000

Scenario 2:
If I send a value between 1001 - 3000 to check, it should return 3000

Scenario 3:
If I send a value between 3001 - 5500 to check, it should return 5500

Scenario 4:
If I send a value between 5501 - 7000 to check, it should return 7000

Scenario 5:
If I send a value above 7000 to check, it should return nothing.

Can I do this with Linq? or what is the most efficient way to do this?

Update: the numbers in maxCheckPoint is dynamic and it can be any values. So we cannot hard coded and check

Comment: Please define nothing. Do you mean `null`?

Comment: @Llama yes. null is okay :)

Comment: looks like you could start with `maxCheckPoint.Where(num => num > whatever).Min()` and refine it from there. What did you try? [mre]? Where is your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with LINQ:

```
int input = 1000;
int? result = numbers
    .OrderBy(n => n) // get the numbers in ascending order
    .SkipWhile(n => n < input) // skip until the remaining set >= input
    .Cast<int?>() // cast to nullable int
    .FirstOrDefault(); // take the first or default entry (if no items remain, it will be null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's too late and my solution is far away from perfect, but:

```
int number = 400; //imput number
        int closest = numbers.Aggregate((x, y) => Math.Abs(x - number) < Math.Abs(y - number) ? x : y); // searching the closer one           
        int compare;
        try{
         if (numbers.IndexOf(closest) != 0)
            {
                compare = Math.Max(closest, numbers[numbers.IndexOf(closest) + 1]); // if it's not 0th and last
            }
            else
            { compare = closest; // if closest with index 0}
        }// check which closest number is bigger 
        catch{            
             compare = closest; // if closest is last
        }
Console.WriteLine(compare);
```